# Стандартный диалог настройки порта

Tags: c#

Как в `c#` вызвать стандартный диалог настройки порта `winapi`?

```
BOOL CommConfigDialog
( 
    LPCTSTR lpszName, // имя устройства
    HWND hWnd,        // указатель на вызываемое окно
    LPCOMMCONFIG lpCC // указатель на структуру дял информации
);
```

Answer (score 1):

на PINVOKE.net есть определения всех нужных структур. вот быстрый тест:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CommConfig
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        // dwProviderSubType
        const UInt32 PST_FAX = 0x00000021; // FAX device
        const UInt32 PST_LAT = 0x00000101; // LAT protocol
        const UInt32 PST_MODEM = 0x00000006; // Modem device
        const UInt32 PST_NETWORK_BRIDGE = 0x00000100; // Unspecified network bridge
        const UInt32 PST_PARALLELPORT = 0x00000002; // Parallel port
        const UInt32 PST_RS232 = 0x00000001; // RS-232 serial port
        const UInt32 PST_RS422 = 0x00000003; // RS-422 port
        const UInt32 PST_RS423 = 0x00000004; // RS-423 port
        const UInt32 PST_RS449 = 0x00000005; // RS-449 port
        const UInt32 PST_SCANNER = 0x00000022; // Scanner device
        const UInt32 PST_TCPIP_TELNET = 0x00000102; // TCP/IP Telnet protocol
        const UInt32 PST_UNSPECIFIED = 0x00000000; // Unspecified
        const UInt32 PST_X25 = 0x00000103; // X.25 standards

        // dwProvCapabilities
        const UInt32 PCF_16BITMODE = 0x0200; // Special 16-bit mode supported
        const UInt32 PCF_DTRDSR = 0x0001; // DTR (data-terminal-ready)/DSR (data-set-ready) supported
        const UInt32 PCF_INTTIMEOUTS = 0x0080; // Interval time-outs supported
        const UInt32 PCF_PARITY_CHECK = 0x0008; // Parity checking supported
        const UInt32 PCF_RLSD = 0x0004; // RLSD (receive-line-signal-detect) supported
        const UInt32 PCF_RTSCTS = 0x0002; // RTS (request-to-send)/CTS (clear-to-send) supported
        const UInt32 PCF_SETXCHAR = 0x0020; // Settable XON/XOFF supported
        const UInt32 PCF_SPECIALCHARS = 0x0100; // Special character support provided
        const UInt32 PCF_TOTALTIMEOUTS = 0x0040; // Total (elapsed) time-outs supported
        const UInt32 PCF_XONXOFF = 0x0010; // XON/XOFF flow control supported

        // dwMaxBaud
        const UInt32 BAUD_075 = 0x00000001; // 75 bps
        const UInt32 BAUD_110 = 0x00000002; // 110 bps
        const UInt32 BAUD_134_5 = 0x00000004; // 134.5 bps
        const UInt32 BAUD_150 = 0x00000008; // 150 bps
        const UInt32 BAUD_300 = 0x00000010; // 300 bps
        const UInt32 BAUD_600 = 0x00000020; // 600 bps
        const UInt32 BAUD_1200 = 0x00000040; // 1200 bps
        const UInt32 BAUD_1800 = 0x00000080; // 1800 bps
        const UInt32 BAUD_2400 = 0x00000100; // 2400 bps
        const UInt32 BAUD_4800 = 0x00000200; // 4800 bps
        const UInt32 BAUD_7200 = 0x00000400; // 7200 bps
        const UInt32 BAUD_9600 = 0x00000800; // 9600 bps
        const UInt32 BAUD_14400 = 0x00001000; // 14400 bps
        const UInt32 BAUD_19200 = 0x00002000; // 19200 bps
        const UInt32 BAUD_38400 = 0x00004000; // 38400 bps
        const UInt32 BAUD_56K = 0x00008000; // 56K bps
        const UInt32 BAUD_57600 = 0x00010000; // 57600 bps
        const UInt32 BAUD_115200 = 0x00020000; // 115200 bps
        const UInt32 BAUD_128K = 0x00040000; // 128K bps
        const UInt32 BAUD_USER = 0x10000000; // Programmable baud rate.


        public enum Parity : byte
        {
            None = 0,
            Odd = 1,
            Even = 2,
            Mark = 3,
            Space = 4,
        }

        public enum StopBits : byte
        {
            One = 0,
            OnePointFive = 1,
            Two = 2
        }

        public enum DtrControl : int
        {
            Disable = 0,
            Enable = 1,
            Handshake = 2
        }
        public enum RtsControl : int
        {
            Disable = 0,
            Enable = 1,
            Handshake = 2,
            Toggle = 3
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct Dcb
        {
            internal uint DCBLength;
            internal uint BaudRate;
            private BitVector32 Flags;

            private ushort wReserved;        // not currently used
            internal ushort XonLim;           // transmit XON threshold
            internal ushort XoffLim;          // transmit XOFF threshold

            internal byte ByteSize;
            internal Parity Parity;
            internal StopBits StopBits;

            internal sbyte XonChar;          // Tx and Rx XON character
            internal sbyte XoffChar;         // Tx and Rx XOFF character
            internal sbyte ErrorChar;        // error replacement character
            internal sbyte EofChar;          // end of input character
            internal sbyte EvtChar;          // received event character
            private ushort wReserved1;       // reserved; do not use

            private static readonly int fBinary;
            private static readonly int fParity;
            private static readonly int fOutxCtsFlow;
            private static readonly int fOutxDsrFlow;
            private static readonly BitVector32.Section fDtrControl;
            private static readonly int fDsrSensitivity;
            private static readonly int fTXContinueOnXoff;
            private static readonly int fOutX;
            private static readonly int fInX;
            private static readonly int fErrorChar;
            private static readonly int fNull;
            private static readonly BitVector32.Section fRtsControl;
            private static readonly int fAbortOnError;

            static Dcb()
            {
                // Create Boolean Mask
                int previousMask;
                fBinary = BitVector32.CreateMask();
                fParity = BitVector32.CreateMask(fBinary);
                fOutxCtsFlow = BitVector32.CreateMask(fParity);
                fOutxDsrFlow = BitVector32.CreateMask(fOutxCtsFlow);
                previousMask = BitVector32.CreateMask(fOutxDsrFlow);
                previousMask = BitVector32.CreateMask(previousMask);
                fDsrSensitivity = BitVector32.CreateMask(previousMask);
                fTXContinueOnXoff = BitVector32.CreateMask(fDsrSensitivity);
                fOutX = BitVector32.CreateMask(fTXContinueOnXoff);
                fInX = BitVector32.CreateMask(fOutX);
                fErrorChar = BitVector32.CreateMask(fInX);
                fNull = BitVector32.CreateMask(fErrorChar);
                previousMask = BitVector32.CreateMask(fNull);
                previousMask = BitVector32.CreateMask(previousMask);
                fAbortOnError = BitVector32.CreateMask(previousMask);

                // Create section Mask
                BitVector32.Section previousSection;
                previousSection = BitVector32.CreateSection(1);
                previousSection = BitVector32.CreateSection(1, previousSection);
                previousSection = BitVector32.CreateSection(1, previousSection);
                previousSection = BitVector32.CreateSection(1, previousSection);
                fDtrControl = BitVector32.CreateSection(2, previousSection);
                previousSection = BitVector32.CreateSection(1, fDtrControl);
                previousSection = BitVector32.CreateSection(1, previousSection);
                previousSection = BitVector32.CreateSection(1, previousSection);
                previousSection = BitVector32.CreateSection(1, previousSection);
                previousSection = BitVector32.CreateSection(1, previousSection);
                previousSection = BitVector32.CreateSection(1, previousSection);
                fRtsControl = BitVector32.CreateSection(3, previousSection);
                previousSection = BitVector32.CreateSection(1, fRtsControl);
            }

            public bool Binary
            {
                get { return Flags[fBinary]; }
                set { Flags[fBinary] = value; }
            }

            public bool CheckParity
            {
                get { return Flags[fParity]; }
                set { Flags[fParity] = value; }
            }

            public bool OutxCtsFlow
            {
                get { return Flags[fOutxCtsFlow]; }
                set { Flags[fOutxCtsFlow] = value; }
            }

            public bool OutxDsrFlow
            {
                get { return Flags[fOutxDsrFlow]; }
                set { Flags[fOutxDsrFlow] = value; }
            }

            public DtrControl DtrControl
            {
                get { return (DtrControl)Flags[fDtrControl]; }
                set { Flags[fDtrControl] = (int)value; }
            }

            public bool DsrSensitivity
            {
                get { return Flags[fDsrSensitivity]; }
                set { Flags[fDsrSensitivity] = value; }
            }

            public bool TxContinueOnXoff
            {
                get { return Flags[fTXContinueOnXoff]; }
                set { Flags[fTXContinueOnXoff] = value; }
            }

            public bool OutX
            {
                get { return Flags[fOutX]; }
                set { Flags[fOutX] = value; }
            }

            public bool InX
            {
                get { return Flags[fInX]; }
                set { Flags[fInX] = value; }
            }

            public bool ReplaceErrorChar
            {
                get { return Flags[fErrorChar]; }
                set { Flags[fErrorChar] = value; }
            }

            public bool Null
            {
                get { return Flags[fNull]; }
                set { Flags[fNull] = value; }
            }

            public RtsControl RtsControl
            {
                get { return (RtsControl)Flags[fRtsControl]; }
                set { Flags[fRtsControl] = (int)value; }
            }

            public bool AbortOnError
            {
                get { return Flags[fAbortOnError]; }
                set { Flags[fAbortOnError] = value; }
            }
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct COMMCONFIG {
            public UInt32 dwSize;
            public UInt16 wVersion;
            public UInt16 wReserved;
            public Dcb dcb;
            public UInt32 dwProviderSubType;
            public UInt32 dwProviderOffsert;
            public UInt32 dwProviderSize;
            public Byte wcProviderDate;
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool CommConfigDialog(string lpszName, IntPtr hWnd, ref COMMCONFIG lpCC);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            COMMCONFIG commConfig = new COMMCONFIG() { dwSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(COMMCONFIG)), dwProviderSubType = PST_RS232, dcb = new Dcb() {BaudRate = BAUD_115200} };
            CommConfigDialog("COM1", IntPtr.Zero, ref commConfig);
            Text = commConfig.dcb.BaudRate.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

с разгону не получилось задавать параметры, которые будут видны в диавлоге, но при выходе из диалога значения скорости порта получаются правильными.
Я думаю, как шаблон для экспериментов сгодится.

Comment: А `unsafe` там зачем?

Comment: с такими определениями структур sizeof без unsafe не работает.

Comment: Тогда ты зря его используешь. В [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sizeof) говорится, что размер структуры после маршаллинга возвращает `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf`, а обычный `sizeof` возвращает размер в managed-среде. Т. е. в твоём случае надо было использовать `Marshal.SizeOf`.

Comment: поправил - убрал unsafe по совету @Qwertiy

Comment: Ага, вижу, держи плюсик :)